# Problema recogiendo array aleatorio php

Tags: php, array

Hola recién encontré esta pregunta . De como sacar elementos aleatorios de un array y decidí crear un código para practicar . este es mi código .

El array lo cargo de una lista de esta manera :

```
$emoj = file(__DIR__."/Datos/Emoji.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

Reviso la variable $emoj usando print_r($emoj);
Y el resultado es un array

```
Array ( [0] =>  [1] => ☺ [2] =>  [3] =>  [4] => ✌ [5] =>  [6] =>  [7] => ☺ [8] =>  [9] => ✌ [10] =>  [11] =>  [12] =>  [13] =>  [14] =>  [15] =>  [16] =>  [17] =>  [18] => ❤ [19] =>  [20] => ‍ [21] =>  [22] =>  [23] =>  [24] =>  [25] =>  [26] =>  [27] =>  [28] =>  [29] =>  [30] => ☺ [31] =>  [32] =>  [33] =>  [34] =>  [35] =>  [36] =>  [37] =>  [38] =>  [39] =>  [40] =>  [41] =>  [42] =>  [43] =>  [44] =>  [45] =>  [46] =>  [47] =>  [48] =>  [49] =>  [50] =>  [51] =>  [52] =>  [53] =>  [54] =>  [55] =>  [56] =>  [57] =>  [58] =>  [59] =>  [60] =>  [61] =>  [62] =>  [63] =>  [64] =>  [65] =>  [66] =>  [67] => ✌ [68] =>  [69] =>  [70] =>  [71] =>  [72] =>  [73] =>  [74] =>  [75] =>  [76] =>  [77] =>  [78] => ❤️❤️❤ [79] =>  [80] =>  [81] =>  [82] =>  [83] =>  [84] =>  [85] =>  [86] =>  [87] =>  [88] => ⭐ [89] =>  [90] =>  [91] => ☀ [92] =>  [93] =>  [94] =>  [95] =>  [96] =>  [97] =>  [98] =>  [99] =>  [100] =>  [101] =>  [102] =>  [103] =>  [104] =>  [105] =>  [106] =>  [107] =>  [108] =>  [109] =>  [110] =>  [111] =>  [112] => ⭐ [113] =>  [114] =>  [115] => ☁ [116] => ⛅ [117] => ⛅ [118] =>  [119] =>  [120] =>  [121] =>  [122] =>  [123] =>  [124] => ❗ [125] => ❕ [126] => ❔ [127] => ❓ [128] => ‼ [129] =>  [130] =>  [131] =>  [132] =>  [133] => ⚫ [134] =>  [135] =>  [136] => ✅ [137] => ✔ [138] => ✖ [139] => ❌ [140] =>  [141] =>  [142] =>  [143] =>  [144] =>  [145] => ♿ [146] =>  [147] =>  [148] =>  [149] =>  [150] =>  [151] =>  [152] =>  [153] => ♂ [154] =>  [155] => ♀ [156] => ♂ [157] =>  [158] =>  [159] =>  [160] =>  [161] => ✈ [162] =>  [163] => ♀ [164] =>  [165] =>  [166] =>  [167] =>  )
```

Luego intento procesarlo de esta manera

```
$N = mt_rand(2,4);
$cla = array_rand($emoj, $N);
$i=0;
foreach($cla as $clave)
{
    $emojis[$i] = str_pad($ele[$clave], 30);
$i++;
}
print_r($emojis);
```

El problema que en ocasiones al imprimir la variable $emojis solo imprime  [0]=> [1]=> o sea sin su valor .

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => )
```

la pregunta es que parte del código esta mal o si existe otra forma mas fácil de lograrlo.

Saludos Cordiales .

Comment: agrega tu arreglo de forma correcta ya que otros usuarios necesitan duplicar el problema para ayudarte. Y 2 te recomiendo leer a detalle que hace cada funcion utilizada!

Comment: Tu *array* ese ... ¿ los elementos están colocados entre comillas, o los tienes tal cual lo has mostrado ?

Comment: El array es el mismo igual al que muestro ese detalle no cambia . y en ocaciones funciona y otras no

Comment: Para crear el array uso file(); solo cargo la lista desde un txt